# What is the Blackberry PlayBook's user agent?

Tags: blackberry, httprequest, user-agent, blackberry-playbook

What is the `User-Agent` string for the Blackberry PlayBook's web browser?

Comment: Hard to tell at this point. (Oct 27,2010) the PlayBook simulator only works for AIR apps at the moment with no access to the browser.  That said someone from RIM should know!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OS 1.0 - According to [RIM](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2011/02/blackberry-playbook-simulator/) it's

```
Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 1.0.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.8+
(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/0.0.1 Safari/534.8+
```

OS 2.0.0

```
Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 2.0.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/535.1+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.2.0.0 Safari/535.1+
```

OS 2.0.1

```
Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 2.0.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/535.8+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.2.0.1 Safari/535.8+
```

OS 2.1.0

```
Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 2.1.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/536.2+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.2.1.0 Safari/536.2+
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, the one for my Playbook (retail) at OS 1.0.1.1690 is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 1.0.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.8+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/0.0.1 Safari/534.8+.
```

Answer (score 2):

The user-agent string from the SDK browser, which is not final or official in any way, looks like this:

```
mozilla/5.0 (x11; u; linux i686; en-us) applewebkit/534.0 (khtml, like gecko)
```

Comment: If case matters, it actually reports: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.0 (KHTML, like Gecko)`

Answer (score 2):

My Playbook is running OS 2.0.1.358, and the `User-Agent` is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (PlayBook; U; RIM Tablet OS 2.0.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/535.8+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.2.0.1 Safari/535.8+
```